After post URL change also automatically change references in posts to that new URL?
After I change the URL of a post there is an automatic redirection AND also some references (aka links) to the old URL are changed to point to the new URL automatically.
For example this automatic reference change happens very nicely in the main menu.
However, the reference to the old URL is still stuck in posts and pages, so there I link to the old (redirected) URL.
Is there anything I can do to auto-change all references to the old URL to directly point to the new (canonical) URL and not to the old (redirected) URL?
Of course I could change the URLs in the DB (with SQL below), but there must be an easier way to extent the automatic link change in the menus to the posts?
"
UPDATE ...._posts
SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'old-URL', 'new-URL')
WHERE
post_status='publish'
AND (
post_content LIKE '%old-URL%')
"
